# How to read values of secrets from K8 cluster using Python?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

Iam trying to use Kubernetes secrets in my code in FastAPI webapp .
I only have `secret name` and `name space` of the cluster.
Is there any documentation on how to access the secret so I could set by db credentials accoring to values present in the secret rather than hardcoding it ?

Any help is aprreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Mount the secrets as a volume in your pod spec. K8s will inject them as files when your pod launches. Read the secrets from those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the secrets as environment variable and then read them using `os.environ["VAR_NAME"]` or `os.getenv("VAR_NAME")`

Note: This solution has nothing to do with FastAPI and is purely K8s + Python. Therefore it might make more sense to rename the topic `How to read values of secrets from K8 cluster using python?` (or similar).

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  username: dXNlcm5hbWU=
  password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: myimage
    env:
      - name: USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: username
      - name: PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: password
  restartPolicy: Never
```